# How to treat %d as a string in JSON

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code, printing, code-snippets

I am using Visual Code Studio as my IDE, and wanted to write a simple snippet for printing:

```
printf("%d", );
```

the snippet:

```
 "Print": {
    "prefix": "printf",
    "body": [
        "printf("%d",$1);",
        "$2"
    ],
    "description": "print"
}
```

It is a JSON file, however it gives me an error with %d and doesnt treat %d as a string, I suppose. The error being: ***Expected commajson(514)***

Comment: You need `\"` instead of `"` inside of the snippet. [Take a look at this](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html).

Comment: The " of printf messes up your json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape double-quotes that appear in strings with a backslash, otherwise it looks like you're ending and restarting the string:

```
 "Print": {
    "prefix": "printf",
    "body": [
        "printf(\"%d\",$1);",
        "$2"
    ],
    "description": "print"
}
```

Comment: thanks! this did the work